# Add UIButtons to data points in a line graph, plotting date and time in X-axis

Tags: swift, uibutton, nsdate, nsdateformatter, linechart

I am trying to plot some data on a simple line graph. Below is my class for storing the data.

How do I plot my `yValue`s with time or date which are strings?

Also, I would like to add `title` as a `UIButton` to each data point in the graph. Tapping on the `UIButton` should display the corresponding `detailedNote` is a small popup.
I have searched and digged into a lot of Chart libraries for iOS but didn't find a way to add this simple functionality.

[graph-with-buttons-at-data-points.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlTZT.png)

Also, what is the way to filter and plot data for "Today", "Last Week", "Last Month" or for any interval of time?

Can I do all of this with iOS libraries like Core Plot and UIBeizerPath without help from any 3rd party frameworks/libraries?
I prefer to use UIBeizerPath as I can smoothen the graph..
https://medium.com/@ramshandilya/draw-smooth-curves-through-a-set-of-points-in-ios-34f6d73c8f9#.28frf03to

Can someone point me to the right resources.. 
Posting swift code is highly appreciated!

```
class NoteEntry {
var title: String?

var detailedNote: String?

var yValue: Float? = 0

let timeString : String  = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    formatter.AMSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.PMSymbol = "PM"
    return formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}()

let dateString: String = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "d"
    return formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}()

let dayOfTheWeekString: String = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE"
    return formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}()

let monthAndYearString: String = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = ""
    return formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer of how to do this with [SwiftCharts](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts):

1. How do I plot my yValues with time or date which are strings?
   You have to convert the strings back to dates. Otherwise the chart will not know how to order them. I also advice to store in your model class dates instead of strings. Do the formatting where you need strings, or have this at least in separate (computed) variables or extensions. About how to make charts with dates in SwiftCharts there are some examples in the library, just orient with them.
2. title as a UIButton
   You can use any kind of UIViews as chart points / overlays / etc. For the line with titles, you would have a line layer and a layer that adds the tappable titles, see e.g. [NotificationsExample](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/NotificationsExample.swift) - which is very near to what you want to do. It uses `HandlingView` instead of `UIButton` to be able to do tap handling in closure instead of using selectors. With selector you would lose context of which chart point you're handling the tap for.
3. Filtering data for "today", "last week" etc.
   I recommend opening a new question for this. You shouldn't bundle together so many questions. This is also not related with the charts library, no charts library will do this for you. You have to use `NSDateComponents`. Maybe there's a library for time operations - as said this is a separate question.
4. Core plot is a third party framework :) You of course can develop a chart from scratch but I'd recommend using a library. For you particular case SwiftCharts seems very suitable, you should be able to get your chart done with a modified version of [NotificationsExample](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/NotificationsExample.swift) to use dates instead of numbers (copy the dates from other example), and adjusting the tappable overlays.

For more questions feel free to comment this or the issue you opened in SwiftCharts.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of SwiftCharts).